# HTML form read only bug

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm new to HTML. I'm trying to create an inline form that consists of readonly plain text and input. However, some part of my output is missing. Expected {{i}} is ('I', 'body') where as output is ('I',  Can anyone suggest what goes wrong? Thanks

[image: Here is jpeg of my frontend]

My html file:

```
<p> Please select the relevant dependency that will add to your output </p>
    {% for i in extraction %}
    {{i}}
    <form class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
          <label for="sampledependency" class="sr-only">Dependency</label>
          <input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="sampledependency" value={{i}}>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mx-sm-3 mb-2">
          <label for="inputpolarity" class="sr-only">Polarity</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputpolarity" placeholder="Polarity">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mb-2">Add</button>
      </form>
    {% endfor %}
```

Here is rendered html_template from flask:

```
return render_template('annotation.html', 
                            first_sentence = first_sentence, 
                            extraction = [('I', 'body'),('d', 'adasd')])
```

Comment: Please show the rendered HTML. I would for example use quotes in ALL form field attributes

Comment: `value=('I', 'body')` will render as `('I,` due to the missing quotes

Comment: yes! i have uploaded rendered_html!

Comment: Not that is NOT "RENDERED". RENDERED means how it looks in view-source of the page: `<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="sampledependency" value=('I', 'body')>` which will have unwanted side effects due to missing quotes. You posted the `renderer`

Comment: Change to `<input type="text" readonly class="form-control-plaintext" id="sampledependency" value="{{i}}">`

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on, honestly, but have you tried wrapping the parentheses with quotes so they're treated as a single unit? ` ["('I', 'body')","('d', 'adasd')"])`